# MYSQL Updating row to maximum value of similar rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this in MYSQL:

```
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   Bob     |  1      |
 2   |   Bob     |  2      |
 3   |   Jack    |  5      |
 4   |   Jack    |  8      |
 5   |   Jack    |  10     |
```

and I'm trying to update the VALUE column to the highest value of rows with same NAME. So the result should be:

```
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   Bob     |  2      |
 2   |   Bob     |  2      |
 3   |   Jack    |  10     |
 4   |   Jack    |  10     |
 5   |   Jack    |  10     |
```

I managed to get the max value like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Value) max FROM `table` GROUP BY Name having count(*) >1 AND MAX(Value) != MIN(Value)
```

But can't figure out how to put it in my update

```
Update table set Value = (SELECT MAX(Value) max FROM `table` GROUP BY Name having count(*) >1 AND MAX(Value) != MIN(Value))
```

Doesn't work. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f79a3/1

```
UPDATE t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(`value`) max_value
           FROM t1 GROUP BY name) t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name
SET t1.value = t2.max_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than other answers are making it.

```
UPDATE MyTable AS t1 INNER JOIN MyTable AS t2 USING (Name)
SET Value = GREATEST(t1.Value, t2.Value);
```

You don't have to find the largest value. You just have to join each row to the set of rows with the same name, and set the Value to the greater Value of the two joined rows. This is a no-op on some rows, but it will apply to every row in turn.

Comment: I already accepted Alex's answer but I like your solution too +1

Answer (score 1):

You may use this query. The table is joined with a subquery (table t2) that contains the results you want to update your table with:

```
UPDATE `table` t1, 
   (SELECT Name, MAX(Value) maxv, MIN(Value) minv
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND maxv != minv) t2
SET t1.Value = t2.maxv
WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

If you want to know how will the values be updated, you can first run an equivalent `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.maxv
FROM `table` t1, 
   (SELECT Name, MAX(Value) maxv, MIN(Value) minv
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND maxv != minv) t2
WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

This query will display all the fields of `table`, followed by the new value `maxv`. You can check the current value and the new value, and if it looks fine, you may run the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Do you mean MIN(value) minv

Comment: is From Name a mistake? did you mean From 'table'?

Comment: also don't you need to check if id's are not equal? t1=name = t2.name will check itself right?

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Yes `Name` was at the wrong place, thank you. Apparently using `id` is not necessary, `Name` is used. I used the query provided in your question that returns the max value as you want it.

Comment: it's giving me an error. This type of clause was previously parsed near Select. Also in your inner select you are not selecting Name how can you later access it in the Where clause

Comment: I added `Name`. I don't understand the error. What is the full error message?

Comment: This is the error: 2 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 44)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT t1.*, t2.maxv FROM `table` t1, ( LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: Does the `SELECT` query execute or not?

Comment: I think you are missing the JOIN. Yes the select by it self runs.

Comment: There is no JOIN missing, it is implied. I tested the SELECT query on my computer and it runs fine. Your tool apparently has bugs in its analysis function.

Comment: This answer (creating a temp table -- t2 in this case) works great. It's all SQL (not stored procedures). It retrieves/calculates the min/max/count/etc first into a temp table in memory, and can then be used to compare with min/max/count on the same table. I wondered if there might be a race condition [maybe not transactional, a write could happen after the READ to put the temp/t2 table in memory] but, in my case, it was fine (my code takes care of preventing that by always cleaning previous data/versions [active/inactive] after an insert).

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table consisting of ID NAME and MAX VALUE as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE1 AS 
(SELECT NAME,MAX(Value) value FROM `table` GROUP BY Name having count(*) >1 
AND MAX(Value) != MIN(Value)
);
```

Use this temporary table to do your update as follows:

```
UPDATE
Table_A
SET
    Table_A.value = Table_B.value
FROM
    `table` AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS Table_B
    ON Table_A.NAME = Table_B.NAME
```

Also this code is somewhat of an approximation as i am not familiar with mysql but i am familiar with sql.

Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: I was hoping to do it in 1 step and 1 query

Answer (score 0):

Simple left join would do the trick.
Try this out and let me know in case of any queries.

```
select a.id,a.name,b.value
from
table a
left join
(select name,max(value) as value from table group by name) b
on a.name=b.name;
```